# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/providers/dao/cache/EhCacheBasedUserCache

Tags: java, spring, jar, ehcache, noclassdeffounderror

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/providers/dao/cache/EhCacheBasedUserCache
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2558)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:859)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1302)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:250)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:394)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1402)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1349)
    ... 35 more
```

I'm getting this error while updating some jars like

**Removed**

- spring-2.5.6.jar

**Added**

- spring-aop-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar
- spring-beans-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar
- spring-context-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar
- spring-context-support-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar
- spring-core-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar
- spring-expression-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar
- spring-jdbc-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar
- spring-orm-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar
- spring-oxm-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar
- spring-tx-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar
- spring-web-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar
- spring-security-config-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar
- spring-security-core-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar
- spring-security-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar

Comment: Try removing all the jar first, and then add only the jars which are required. There could be some ambiguity within the jars.

Comment: Already tried :-(

Comment: The reason is `EhCacheBasedUserCache` is no more in that package since Spring Security 3+, so there's actually no `org/springframework/security/providers/dao/cache/EhCacheBasedUserCache` class. Now its location is `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.cache.EhCacheBasedUserCache`. I don't know how to fix it, but there must be some library pointing to that path, you can find it and replace it with its newer version.

Comment: Seems you have some old Spring (or own) code using this class with old namespace. Try searching for usages of `EhCacheBase‌​dUserCache` in your project and find those with `.../dao/cache` namespace and figure out how to replace them with new 'version' of class.